# Optimizing pyspark job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and I am trying to make my pyspark job more efficient, it is very slow when applying it to big data. The objective is to take phrase and its count and turn then into counts of unique words and n-most frequent and least frequent words with the associated count.

Im my first 2 processing steps, I am using lambda function to multiply the phrases by counts and then I use `flatMap` to turn int into a list of all words.

To illustrate, the first map step with lambda function followed by flatMap turns the following input into a flat list of each word that then can be counted

```
good morning \t 1
hello \t 3
goodbye \t 1
```

turns into `[good, morning, hello, hello, hello, goodbye]` or even if the `flatMap` is the right approach and whether to use a `reduceByKey` approach

Any feedback on how I can significantly optimize the performance of this job? Thank you! The pyspark function is:

```
def top_bottom_words(resilent_dd, n):
    """
    outputs total unique words and n top and bottom words with count for each of the words

    input:
    resilent_dd, n
    where:
    resilent_dd: resilient distributed dataset with form of (phrase) \t (count)
    n: number of top and bottom words to output

    output:
    total, n_most_freqent , n_least_freqent

    where:
    total: count of unique words in the vocabulary
    n_most_freqent: n top words of highest counts with count for each of the words
    n_least_freqent: n bottom words of lowest counts with count for each of the words
    """

    total, top_n, bottom_n = None, None, None

    resilent_dd.persist()
    phrases = resilent_dd.map(
        lambda line: " ".join(
            [line.split("\t")[0] for i in range(int(line.split("\t")[1]))]
        )
    )
    phrases = phrases.flatMap(lambda line: line.lower().split(" "))
    word_counts = phrases.countByValue()

    total = len(word_counts)

    n_most_freqent = sorted(word_counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:n]
    n_least_freqent = sorted(word_counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[:n]
    resilent_dd.unpersist()

    return total, n_most_freqent, n_least_freqent
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar question, this approach works well and is fast

```
    total, n_most_freqent, n_least_freqent = None, None, None
    
    phrases = resilent_dd.map(lambda line: (line.split("\t")[0].lower().split(" "), int(line.split("\t")[1]))) \
        .flatMap(lambda x: [(word, x[1]) for word in x[0]]) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) \
        .sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending=False)

    total = phrases.count()
    
    n_most_freqent = phrases.take(n)
    n_least_freqent = phrases.takeOrdered(n, key=lambda x: x[1])
    
    return total, n_most_freqent, n_least_freqent
```